# Converting Crystal Reports criteria to a SQL Server criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having problems converting this Crystal Reports criteria to a SQL Server criteria.

```
datefield >= iif(month(today)=1, minimum(LastYearYTD), minimum(YearToDate))
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't know how to convert the IF statement but if you open the report in Crystal there is a `Show SQL Query` under the `Database` menu option that will give you the SQL code it sends for the report. Give that a look to see if it gives you what you need

Comment: @user3170315 Have you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
(datefield >= minimum(LastYearYTD) AND month(today)=1) 
OR 
(datefield >= minimum(YearToDate) AND month(today)<>1)
```